# vba - AfterUpdate() event - Automatically move to next control

Tags: vba, ms-access, events

i have the following problem:

In my Form i have three controls, textboxes - that are to be filled by a barcode scanner. The controls are:

```
Textbox1
Textbox2
Textbox3
```

I want the form to move automatically to the next form when each gets filled with content. In the spirit of that, 
    Textbox1 -> Has a unit mask of 26 characters
    Textbox2 -> Once textbox1 is full, it autotabs here.

- Here is the problem : The barcode read for textbox2 is surrounded by  tags and 4 lines long, which makes it hard to specify a unitmask for it. I want it to automatically move to Textbox3 on some trigger.

I have tried the AfterUpdate() event on Textbox2, and using .setfocus() in there to redirect the focus to Textbox3, but it doesnt work - what i found online is that for this event to trigger, either the unitmask needs to be satisfied, or th e maximum length (which isnt static).

Is there another way to go about this? I used this code for Barcode1 :

```
Private Sub Barcode1_AfterUpdate()
    ' After Update Event - Barcode 1
' Cuts substring and assigns to ValuePrice
'

'MsgBox ("In Barcode1_AfterUpdate")
Me.Barcode2.SetFocus
fld = Barcode1.Value
If (fld = "11111111111111111111111111") Then
    MsgBox ("Special Scenario Triggered")
    Me.Barcode2.SetFocus
Else
    price = Mid(fld, 17, 9)
    ValuePrice.Value = price
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe you should use OnChange event instead. It triggered on each typed character

Comment: you can add a Length condition over here, if the length of the textbox 2 is greater than a value, trim the value after that and paste it in textbox 3

Comment: Barcode scanners can usually be programmed to append a CR/LF to the scanned code; that would do it all automatically for you.